# Is it possible to exclude stops from routing through the code in OpenTripPlanner?

Tags: java, gtfs, opentripplanner

I try to exclude a stop from routing through the code.
I create gtfs realtime Alert

```
public class ServiceAlertStop {

  GtfsRealtime.FeedMessage feedMessage;

  public GtfsRealtime.FeedMessage config(){
    GtfsRealtime.FeedMessage.Builder feedMessageBuilder = 
    GtfsRealtime.FeedMessage.newBuilder();

    GtfsRealtime.FeedHeader.Builder header = 
    GtfsRealtime.FeedHeader.newBuilder();
    header.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    header.setIncrementality(GtfsRealtime.FeedHeader.
    Incrementality.FULL_DATASET);
    header.setGtfsRealtimeVersion("1.0");
    feedMessageBuilder.setHeader(header);

    GtfsRealtime.FeedEntity.Builder entity = 
    GtfsRealtime.FeedEntity.newBuilder();
    entity.setId("0");

    GtfsRealtime.Alert.Builder alert = GtfsRealtime.Alert.newBuilder();
    alert.setCause(GtfsRealtime.Alert.Cause.UNKNOWN_CAUSE);
    alert.setEffect(GtfsRealtime.Alert.Effect.STOP_MOVED);

    GtfsRealtime.TimeRange.Builder activePeriod = 
    alert.addActivePeriodBuilder();
    activePeriod.setStart(System.currentTimeMillis());
    activePeriod.setEnd(System.currentTimeMillis() + 172800000);
    GtfsRealtime.TranslatedString.Builder translatedString = 
    GtfsRealtime.TranslatedString.newBuilder();
    GtfsRealtime.TranslatedString.Translation.Builder translation = 
    GtfsRealtime.TranslatedString.Translation.newBuilder();
    translation.setLanguage("en");
    translation.setText("Stop is closed!");
    translatedString.addTranslation(translation);
    alert.setDescriptionText(translatedString);

    alert.setHeaderText(translatedString);

    GtfsRealtime.EntitySelector.Builder entitySelector = 
    alert.addInformedEntityBuilder();
    entitySelector.setStopId("22126");

    entity.setAlert(alert);
    feedMessageBuilder.addEntity(entity);
    feedMessage = feedMessageBuilder.build();
    return feedMessage;
  }

  public void run(Graph graph){
    AlertsUpdateHandler updateHandler = new AlertsUpdateHandler();
    updateHandler.setEarlyStart(1);
    updateHandler.setFeedId("1");
    updateHandler.setAlertPatchService(new AlertPatchServiceImpl(graph));
    updateHandler.setFuzzyTripMatcher(new 
    GtfsRealtimeFuzzyTripMatcher(graph.index));
    updateHandler.update(feedMessage);

  }
}
```

ASCII representation of an my Alert

```
header {
  gtfs_realtime_version: "1.0"
  incrementality: FULL_DATASET
  timestamp: 1493520112381
}
  entity {
    id: "0"
    alert {
      active_period {
        start: 1493520112415
        end: 1493692912415
      }
    informed_entity {
      stop_id: "22126"
    }
    cause: UNKNOWN_CAUSE
    effect: STOP_MOVED
    header_text {
      translation {
        text: "Stop is closed!"
        language: "en"
      }
    }
    description_text {
      translation {
        text: "Stop is closed!"
        language: "en"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I load it in otp after the graph is built, in class OTPMain.java

```
ServiceAlertStop serviceAlertStop = new ServiceAlertStop(); 
serviceAlertStop.config(); 
serviceAlertStop.run(graphService.getRouter().graph);
```

After that i don't receive error, but when i begin planner trip this stop (22126) also exist in new route(( I need that otp don't use this stop. Is it possible to exclude stops from routing through the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the OpenTripPlanner API to do your trip planning, there is a 'bannedStops' and 'bannedStopsHard' parameter you can set in the [plan API call](http://dev.opentripplanner.org/apidoc/1.0.0/resource_PlannerResource.html) that will force the router to ignore a stop.